# Is using trimmer equal to razor for shaving new born baby hair?

Tags: sunnah

As the question applies that I am trying to find out if trimmer shave is equal to razor shaving.? People prefer trimmer as it’s more for layman and easy to use, but according to sunnah what is recommend?

Comment: A trimmer can give you a pretty close cut but it definitely cant give you a shave that a straight razor or cartridge razor can.  But I'd love to know the ijtehad of Ulema on this question.

Comment: The sunnah is حلق (shaving) and not تقصير (clipping).

Comment: @UmH do u have a reference to quote?